# How to get the shape of an image after decode_jpeg in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, image, tensorflow

I have an image which I have feed into tf.image.decode_jpeg:

```py
img = tf.io.read_file(file_path)
img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(img, channels=3)
```

and I am trying to get its height and with width `img.shape[0]` and `img.shape[1]`, but both return `None`. Actually, `img.shape` returns `(None, None, 3)`.

I am using this inside a function that is mapped into a `tf.data.Dataset`. How can I get the real shape of the image?

**update:**

At the moment, I have found a solution that consists in wrapping the code with `tf.py_function` to execute it eagerly because the dataset creates an internal graph. I would appreciate If anyone has another solution to do it in a pure graph way, which would improve performance.

Comment: Hi @Diego Palacios, can you share the exact image you're trying to load?

Comment: Hi @TF_Support, I was using the images from the ILSVRC, but I am no longer working on this. I just used the solution with the 'tf.py_function'.

Comment: Hi @Diego Palacios, That is noted.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have already found a solution to get the shape of the image by wrapping your code around `tf.py_function`. Providing the solution here for the benefit of the community.

However, since eager execution is enabled by default in TensorFlow 2, you can get the shape directly like mentioned below without having to wrap it around `tf.py_function`.

**Tensorflow 1.x:**

```
img = tf.io.read_file("sample.jpg")
img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(img, channels=3)

with tf.Session() as sess:
  array = img.eval(session=sess)
  height = array.shape[0]
  width = array.shape[1]
  print("Height:",height)
  print("Width:",width)
```

> Height:320
>
> Width:320

**Tensorflow 2:**

```
img = tf.io.read_file("sample.jpg")
img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(img, channels=3)
height = img.shape[0]
width = img.shape[1]

print("Height:",height)
print("Width:",width)
```

> Height: 320
>
> Width: 320